# How to change file name of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to remove special character from image file name:

```
<input type="file" id="txtSelectAvatar" multiple="multiple" accept='image/*'/>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#txtSelectAvatar").on("change", function(e) {
    alert (e.target.files[0].name) //=> Foto+13.jpg
    var newFileName = e.target.files[0].name.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%'":*?<>{}]/g,'_')
    alert(newFileName) //=> Foto_13.jpg
}
```

I tried many ways but cannot really change the file name of `e.target.files[0].name`

Can anyone help me with this issue? Thanks alot.

Comment: you want to change file name which being downloaded?

Comment: You show us that you can already change it, but you're just setting a new variable (`newFileName`). You're never actually doing anything with this value.

Comment: You should change you file name on server side when uploading it.

Comment: not sure you can change the name property on the `File` object...

Comment: hi @KalpeshSingh, it is upload function.

Comment: If you want your user to download file with what you want specify then use HTML5's `download="[YOUR SPECIFIED FILE NAME]"` attribute

Comment: hi @cakan, the problem is it is also hard to change the file from server side, from server side I have MultipartFile, and there is a very tough way to change the original file name.

Comment: below is ajax upload:   $('#formUploadAvatar').ajaxSubmit(function(data) {
                        $("#txtSelectAvatar").val("");
                        $('body').trigger({
                            type:"updateavatar",
                            response:{
                                avatarUrl: data.assetUrl
                            }
                        });
                    });